# Python - How can I send a rsa.key.PublicKey object through socket?

Tags: python, sockets, rsa

I'm using the python rsa module to generate a public/private key pair. I want to send the public key to the other computer through a socket connection.

When I try to encode the public key to send it, I get this error:

```
  File "chatclient.py", line 128, in <module>
    s.sendall(pubkey.encode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'PublicKey' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I cannot figure out a way to encode the key other than the method that causes the error. If I try to convert it to a string, encode it and send it through, I cannot use the key to encrypt any messages, nor are there any documented ways to turn it back into a PublicKey object.

This is what causes the error:

```
s.sendall(pubkey.encode('utf-8'))
```

Here's the package on pypi and the documentation:

https://pypi.org/project/rsa/

https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/usage.html

Comment: What package do you use here? Where is the `PublicKey` class defined?

Comment: the `.encode` is usually a string thing what type of object is `pubkey`? check to see if it already haves a `bytes` or `to_bytes` method

Comment: @Nullman I've checked at https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/reference.html, and the class rsa.PublicKey doesn't have anything like that.

Comment: You should be able to save the key as a string with `save_pkcs1` and load it from said string with `load_pkcs1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use save_pkcs1 and load_pkcs1:

```
a = pubkey.save_pkcs1(format='DER')
b = rsa.key.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(a, format='DER')
```